# Access List<T> when T is internal class

Tags: c#, reflection, access-modifiers

The field that I access is of type `List<EntityNetPlayer>`, and the `EntityNetPlayer` class is internal (from an external assembly).

How do I make a List field to that class?

```
public static object GetAlivePlayers(object instance) =>
    instance.GetType()
    .GetField("AlivePlayers", BindingFlags.Instance |BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetValue(instance)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make a list of that type"? Isn´t the value returned already of that type? Or do you mean you want `GetActivePlayer` return a `List<EntityNetPlayer>` insterad of `object`? This is not possible at all, because the actual type of your list is only known at **runtime**, not at **compile-time**.

Comment: CAn you provide additional code? Specifically the EntityNetPlayer class code and the code encapsulating it (the class where it was delcared)?

Comment: The `object` that you obtain already _is_ a `List<EntityNetPlayer>`. The problem is that you can't refer to it at compile time. You could cast it to `IList` to access the individual objects inside it.

Comment: If a class/property/etc is private, I'ts not possible to use it outside it's scope. Thats the declaration of private. You can read the class, it's properties etc via reflection (if you're allowed to) and create your own copy and use it

Comment: IList did the job, Thanks!